# Is there a way to stop Spring from rollbacking every transaction in a test method and do a Rollback after it executes?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, spring-transactions

I'm trying to write some integration tests for an app that I write as a practise. I have a test class with @Transactional annotation on it, to stop tests from committing any changes to db. I've noticed that rollback happens for every method of JPA repository I use. When I save an entity and then try to find a values for mentioned entity I get an empty List since that entity does not exists in DB. So do I have to change my approach or is there a way to wrap all of test method contents into a single transaction that will be rolledback after test method is done running?

Service that is tested:

```
@Service
public class FridgeServiceImpl implements FridgeService {

    private final FridgeRepository fridgeRepository;

    public FridgeServiceImpl(FridgeRepository fridgeRepository) {
        this.fridgeRepository = fridgeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Fridge save(Fridge fridge) {
        return fridgeRepository.save(fridge);
    }

    @Override
    public List<IngredientInFridge> getAllInFridge(Long id) {
        return fridgeRepository.findAllInFridge(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<IngredientInFridge> getAllToExpireAfterDate(LocalDate date) {
        return fridgeRepository.findAllWithExpirationDateAfter(date);
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface FridgeRepository extends JpaRepository<Fridge, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select i from Fridge f join f.fridgeContents i where i.id.fridgeId = :fridgeId")
    List<IngredientInFridge> findAllInFridge(@Param("fridgeId") Long fridgeId);

    @Query(value = "select i from IngredientInFridge i inner join IngredientGrammage ig on i.ingredient.id = ig.ingredient.id where i.fridge.id = :fridgeId " +
            "and ig.recipe.id = :recipeId")
    Set<IngredientInFridge> getIngredientsAvailableForRecipe(@Param("recipeId") Long recipeId, @Param("fridgeId") Long fridgeId);

    @Query(value = "select i from IngredientInFridge i where i.expirationDate <= :date")
    List<IngredientInFridge> findAllWithExpirationDateAfter(@Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@Transactional
class FridgeServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    FridgeService fridgeService;
    Ingredient ingredient;
    Fridge fridge;
    IngredientInFridge ingredientInFridge;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        ingredient = new Ingredient(100, "Chicken", UnitOfMeasure.G);
        fridge = new Fridge(new HashSet<>());
        ingredientInFridge = new IngredientInFridge(ingredient, fridge, 50, LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 30));
        fridge.addToFridge(ingredientInFridge);
    }

    @Test
    void getAllInFridge_ThenReturn_1() {
        //given
        var savedFridge = fridgeService.save(fridge); //save an entity

        //when
        var ingredientsInFridge = fridgeService.getAllInFridge(savedFridge.getId()); //empty List since fridgeService.save(fridge) was rolledback.

        //then
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, savedFridge.getFridgeContents().size());
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, ingredientsInFridge.size()); // failed assertion
    }
```

Test config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "com.calculate.calories.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:applicationTest.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.calculate.calories.service", "com.calculate.calories.repository"})
@EntityScan("com.calculate.calories.model")
public class TestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.calculate.calories.model");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        //JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        //transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return properties;
    }
```

I tried to use JpaTransactionManager instead of DataSourceTransactionManager but if I do so, there are no rollbacks for the tests and db is flooded with duplicate data. I've also attempted changing
@Transactional from class level to method level but it changed nothing.

I've seen this post: [Does @Transactional annotation on test methods rollback every transaction in the annotated method before it gets to the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611944/does-transactional-annotation-on-test-methods-rollback-every-transaction-in-the)

But when I try to use the EntityManager.flush() after saving it throws javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Comment: The problem is tha tyou have a test config which uses the wrong transaction manager. You are using JPA and should use the `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum  if I change it to 'JpaTransactionManager' there are no rollbacks happening and all test entities are saved to DB.

Comment: You are using MySQL make sure you use tables that support transactions, the default (MyISAM) doesn't support this. I would strongly suggest to ditch your specific configuration and use `@SpringBootTest` instead of what you have now.

Comment: @M.Deinum my default storage engine is set as 'InnoDB' so transactions should be enabled from what I understand.
I've changed annotatnions on test class to:
`@SpringBootTest(classes = {com.calculate.calories.service.FridgeService.class, com.calculate.calories.service.impl.FridgeServiceImpl.class, com.calculate.calories.repository.FridgeRepository.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/applicationTest.properties")
@Transactional`
But it creates a problem with not having JPA Repositories enabled. If I will add annotation to enable those I will need to configure EM factory as well.

Comment: And that will push me again to `@Import` a separate configuration

Comment: I think that problem with `@SpringBootTest `is that I'm testing a service layer that has dependency on persistance layer, but my `@SpringBootApplication` is in other layer to which service layer does not have dependency so it can't configure whole ApplicationContext as it can't find `@SpringBootConfiguration`

Comment: You should have a plain `@SpringBootTest` don't add the classes stuff.

Comment: @M.Deinum using only `@SpringBootTest` causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`, this test is placed in layer that does not ahve access to `@SpringBootApplication` so `@SpringBootTest` will not set up applciation context

Comment: Point it to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. This basically means you aren't following the suggested package structure. Which probably also means you have additional `@CompontScan` etc. on `@Configuration`/`@SpringBootApplication` classes?

Comment: @M.Deinum there are in separate modules.
I have modules declared:  **config, persistence, common ,application, web** in my parent POM, tests are in application module, while `@SpringBootApplication` in in config module. application module has dependency for persistence module only.

Comment: Which explains your, imho, weird test setup. Nonetheless if transactional wouldn't work the record would be available, as the rollback is only for the transactional on test not the other ones. There should be 1 transaction spanning your test method or a lot of individual transactions. Either way you are using the wrong transaction manager, you wold also need `@EnableTransactionManagement` as you are now totally bypassing all forms of auto-configuration you need to configure everything yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Yeah I tried to divide application into modules, but when I think about it now, I might just place all integration tests in the module that has `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, it is a learning experience so it does not have to be perfect for now.